# Increment counter inside an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to increment (using a counter) the value of a C# array. However I always get an error:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is my code.

```
while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    string[] parts = new string[40];
    parts=line.Split(' ');
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a <= (parts.Length - 1); a++)
    {

        if (parts[a] == "if")
        {
            node = node + 1;
            edge = edge + 1;
            int b = a + 2;
            Console.Write(parts[b]);
            if ((parts[a + 2]) == "{")
            {
                node = node + 1;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line? Did you debug your code? http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ You can find your problem easily with debugging.

Comment: is it on this line? 'if ((parts[a + 2]) == "{")' ?

Comment: `new string[40]` is a waste of time and memory because the next statement assigns a new value.  Just use `var part = line.Split(' ');`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is `parts[a + 2]` when you reached to the end a+2 is out of bounds of array

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that

`parts[a + 2]` doesn't exceed the array length?

One solution could be as follows:

```
while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    string[] parts = new string[40];
    parts=line.Split(' ');
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a <= (parts.Length - 1); a++)
    {

        if (parts[a] == "if")
        {
            node = node + 1;
            edge = edge + 1;
            int b = a + 2;
            Console.Write(parts[b]);
            if (((a + 2) < parts.length) && (parts[a + 2]) == "{")
            {
                node = node + 1;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

In the code an extra check is put to see if a + 2 doesn't exceed the length of the parts-array. Then, the check is done, if the contents at array index a + 2 is equal to "{". If both conditions are true, then the code inside the block is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use parts[a+2] you can only do the for loop until parts.Lenth -2:

```
while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    string[] parts = new string[40];
    parts=line.Split(' ');
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a <= (parts.Length - 2); a++)
    {

        if (parts[a] == "if")
        {
            node = node + 1;
            edge = edge + 1;
            int b = a + 2;
            Console.Write(parts[b]);
            if ((parts[a + 2]) == "{")
            {
                node = node + 1;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
int b = a + 2;
Console.Write(parts[b]); // here is the first problem
if ((parts[a + 2]) == "{") // why do a+2 here when you know parts[b] is the same thing (a +2)
{
      node = node + 1;
}
```